# Any easier way to assign values of a DataFrame row to corresponding variables in a custom object?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

Let's say I have the following DataFrame with some sample rows:

```
         id    first_name   last_name   age
   0     1     John         Doe         18
   1     2     Joe          Shmuck      21
```

Let's say I also have a custom Python class called `Person` which ought to represent the values of the DataFrame above.  For convenience, the DataFrame's column names correspond exactly to the attributes of the class.

```
class Person:
    id
    first_name
    last_name
    age
```

I understand I can retrieve the values directly from a row (of a DataFrame) by providing the column index or the column name e.g: `df.iloc[0]['age']` however I want to have a slightly safer coding practice throughout my application and call `person.age` or even better a getter `person.get_age()`.

The only, primitive way I'm doing is iterating through the columns of a row of my DataFrame, retrieving each cell and assigning them to the variables of new Person object one by one. e.g: `person.first_name = df.loc[0]['first_name']`

Is there a helpful tool which DataFrame, or Series, or any other Python library provides to streamline this?  i.e. some wishful thinking like `person = df.loc[0].transform(type=Person)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need a class for this? You can use `df.itertuples` to create a list of "Person" `namedtuple`s:

```
>>> list(df.itertuples(index=False, name='Person'))
```

```
[Person(id=1, first_name='John', last_name='Doe', age=18),
 Person(id=2, first_name='Joe', last_name='Shmuck', age=21)
]
```

A namedtuple behaves a lot like a class in the sense that you can access its attributes (`p.age`, `p.id`, and so on).

```
for p in df.itertuples(index=False, name='Person'):
    print(p.first_name)

John
Joe
```

Comment: This is very useful actually. I may adopt your approach and free my project from these models then.  If no other answers come up, I will happily accept your answer.  Thank you.

Comment: @serkanozel yeah, pandas devs think of everything. You're welcome.